# Is this how a broken graphic card looks like?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, bsod, gpu

I have a Sony Vaio VGN-FW51JF model that comes with ATI Mobility Radeon HD4570 graphic card. The OS installed is Windows 7 sp2. It was working fine up until yesterday morning.

It suddenly started to become slow when gaming and eventually a message notifying me that my computer was low on memory and a program should be terminated came up now and then like [this](http://i.technet.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC134909.gif), but I didnt pay much attention to it. I was monitoring the usage of my RAM however the entire time and I haven't seen it go past 60% usage at any time. When I closed the notification (without closing the program mentioned) the performance improved. This happened 2 or 3 times yesterday. After I have finished my game I browsed the Internet for a couple of hours without noticing any difference. Today this notification came up once again but again I didn't pay any attention to it.

A few hours ago I was watching a local TV Stream when the computer unexpectedly restarted.

Starting Windows normally after "Windows Recovery" displays the same "bars" while loading Windows but it ends up in a blue screen before the loading is complete which is too "scrumbled" so I cant read anything useful out of it.

Starting in Safe mode works but it ends up being worse than before. You can see it in the album I have posted. I can't make out any of the information on screen but there are certainy some errors popping up in there.

*Sorry for the low quality photos but my cellphone is rather old.*

[image]
[image]
[image]

What would be the troubleshooting steps to follow to make sure that my GPU has probably RIPed?

Comment: I would strongly suspect a bad power supply.

Comment: Its a laptop.  Its unlikely the power supply.  I suspect its a display issue though.

Comment: @Ramhound if it's a display issue connecting to an external monitor should work am I right? I won't be able to do that for the next couple of hours but it *should* work.

Comment: If it costs $0 to check, then you have nothing to lose, really the only way to eliminate a possibility.

Comment: If it's a graphics card issue, connecting to an external monitor may or may not work. If it's an LCD panel issue, you'd expect an external monitor to work. If it's a RAM issue, you'd expect to see other non-graphics related errors as well (and memtest86 could help). It is highly unlikely to be a power supply issue. It is much more likely to be graphics or display hardware based on the patterns. It could also be some motherboard issue. Is this under warranty?

Comment: @JasonC Unfortunately not. The warranty has expired a long time ago, but then again this gives me freedom to open it up and work something out of it.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually facing this problem and I think it is not a graphic card problem playing with monitor wire fixed my problem.

Comment: Agreed. This problem could arise from either dying panel, dying graphics processor, dying cable, or loose connections.